# MS Access "Record is deleted" error in query with SELECT DISTINCT ORDER BY DESC

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, distinct

MS Access 2016 query with "DISTINCT" fails when ordering by "DESC" but works when ordering by "ASC".

The following query fails with "Record is deleted":

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProcessDate FROM Info_Table ORDER BY ProcessDate DESC;
```

But changing "DESC" to "ASC" or removing the "DISTINCT" keyword causes the query to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProcessDate FROM Info_Table ORDER BY ProcessDate ASC; 
SELECT ProcessDate FROM Info_Table ORDER BY ProcessDate ASC; 
SELECT ProcessDate FROM Info_Table ORDER BY ProcessDate DESC;
```

**The questions:**

- Is it "normal" for a query to fail when using DESC but to work when using ASC?
- If "yes" then how do I structure the query so that it always returns the distinct values instead of failing with the "Record is deleted" error?
- If "no" then how do I get rid of the "Record is deleted" error?

*Other information:*

- The field "ProcessDate" is defined as Date/Time with no formats, input mask, validation rules, etc. -- just a plain date/time field.
- Info_Table has 15,000 records. 70 records do not have a value in "ProcessDate".
- A "successful" query returns 54 rows.
- The failure mode is the same whether running in VBA code or directly on the table in SQL design view.
- I've looked at other questions involving DISTINCT and the "Record is deleted" error but have not found anything else to try.

*I have tried (without success):*

```
SELECT DISTINCT Info_Table.ProcessDate FROM Case_Info_Table ORDER BY Info_Table.ProcessDate DESC; 

SELECT [ProcessDate] FROM [Info_Table] GROUP BY [ProcessDate] ORDER BY MAX([ProcessDate]) DESC;
```

Comment: You probably have some corruption in the database. Have you done Compact & Repair? Next step: import everything into a new database.

Comment: Yes, I did try C&R. Thanks for the suggestion. As to db corruption, ugh, I thought about that but was hoping it might be "user error" as the db is pretty big.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. DISTINCT with DESC works for me.

Comment: Here are some more (and more specific) ideas: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html